# Link (With Driver) a Custom Property Value to a newly generated piece of Text

Tags: python

> #### [image: AI Icon] Warning, Potential AI generated content⚠️
>
> **This post is suspected to have been generated with the help of an artificial intelligence, chat bot, or other language model tools without proper attribution.**
>
> There is reason to believe this post was not written by a human due to its structure, and grammatical construction, and has been marked by our community.
> Current AI chat bots are a language models, that means they are like a parrot, they can mimic human language well, but they are built to write **seemingly** logical, **seemingly** factual grammatically valid text, rather than actually **be correct**, like a human would.
> The veracity of the following content cannot be ascertained.
> See the [Concerns regarding AI generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396).

I'm trying to create a piece of Blender Text that is linked via a driver to the value of a custom property.  The following keeps throwing an error:

```
import bpy

# Check if there is an active object
if bpy.context.active_object is None:
    print("Please select an object first.")
else:
    selected_object = bpy.context.active_object
    
    # Check if the selected object has the specified custom property
    custom_property_name = "0V Description"
    if custom_property_name not in selected_object:
        print(f"The selected object does not have the custom property '{custom_property_name}'.")
    else:
        # Create a new text object
        bpy.ops.object.text_add()
        text_object = bpy.context.active_object
        text_object.name = "Custom_Text"
        
        # Create a custom property on the text object for the driver
        text_object["_RNA_UI"] = {"Custom_Driver_Property": {"description": "Custom Driver Property", "default": 0.0, "min": 0.0, "max": 1.0}}
        text_object["Custom_Driver_Property"] = 0.0
        
        # Set the custom property to the value of the custom property of the selected object
        text_object["Custom_Driver_Property"] = selected_object[custom_property_name]
        
        # Access the driver of the custom property and set its expression
        driver = text_object.driver_add("['Custom_Driver_Property']")
        driver.expression = f'\"{selected_object[custom_property_name]}\"'
```

Comment: Hello. what's the error ?

Comment: Blender vanilla text objects contents can't be driven because it doesn't support animation. You'll have to use special callbacks for that

Comment: Thanks Gorgeous, I will have a look at 'special callbacks'.  I'm a big fan of yours in the OSArch discussion group!

Comment: Hehe cheers. You can look into property group and / or StringProperty (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) which you can add an update callback to and tweak the text in there

Comment: Yeah, I'll take a look at the StringProperty.  My latest attempt went mad and nearly crashed Blender.  It added a LOT of Text objects rather than just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proposal based on your explanation :

- Define a custom prop on `bpy.types.Object`.
- Add a callback to its `update` method, that will update a children text object's body and create one if it doesn't exist yet.
- Since this is a API defined property you can't modify it using the UI anymore so define a new panel to display the prop.

[image]

```py
import bpy


def update_text(self, context):
    obj = self
    for text_obj in obj.children:
        if text_obj.type == "FONT":
            text = text_obj.data
            break
    else:  # No text children yet
        text = bpy.data.curves.new(name=obj.name + "_text", type="FONT")
        text_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(object_data=text, name=obj.name + "_text")
        text_obj.parent = obj
        text_obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world
        obj.users_collection[0].objects.link(text_obj)
        text_obj.show_in_front = True

    text.body = self.my_string_property


class CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(context.object, "my_string_property")


bpy.utils.register_class(CustomPanel)
bpy.types.Object.my_string_property = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="My String Property", update=update_text)
```

Comment: That is amazing! 

Now I need to work out how to get it to show in a DXF made with the PRJ addon.  

Great work Gorgious!

Comment: Cheers. It will be converted to a mesh object on export so it won't export to an Autocad Text object but will show up as a bunch of polylines. In my experience it will lead to artifacts when zoomed out if you plan on printing it. Depends on your end goal

Comment: What is your process for creating technical drawings?  (cheeky question - apologies)
I've been trying all sorts of addons (TechSec, Measurable etc) and methods - from exporting to DXF to using Blender's compositor (one camera with a different position per Frame).